# Подскажите, как убрать точки 0 из графика?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Вот построил оси, но как убрать с них 0 точки не могу разобраться. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: код стоит как текст (с форматированием) в вопрос добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Matplotlib` есть целый набор *локаторов и форматтеров*. В данном случае можно использовать [FixedLocator](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator). При известных пределах осей, можно строго задать набор выводимых значений. Если нас устраивает тот вариант, который дает `AutoLocator` по-умолчанию, значит, сохраним количество `ticks`, исключив лишь ноль.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
import numpy as np

LIMITS = -10, 10

plt.axis([*LIMITS] * 2)  # границы для X и Y одинаковы
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ticks = np.linspace(*LIMITS, len(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()))
# array([-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ,   2.5,   5. ,   7.5,  10. ])

ticks = ticks[ticks != 0]

ff = FixedLocator(ticks)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ff)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ff)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам грубый подход к решению проблемы - индекс надписей над началом координат я вычислил эмпирическим путём. А это не совсем правильно. Но с вычислением индекса, думаю, вы разберетесь.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.axis([-10,10,-10,10])
ax=plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
xticks[4].label1.set_visible(False) # <- [4] - это индекс метки для '0'
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[4].label1.set_visible(False)


plt.show()
```

[image: zero label removed]